# Insert into query with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I need to insert into posts table, Its work good and insert 114 posts from another table, but the problem is in the insert to another table, another table needs the post id to insert to other tables, I can get the last id only, but I need all posts id.

How can do that

```
global $wpdb;

$query1 =  "INSERT INTO wpr9_posts ( `post_date`,`post_content`,`post_title`,`post_status`,`post_name`,`post_type` )  SELECT '2020-08-28 18:30:43', `image`,`name`,'publish',`id`,'post' FROM `play` WHERE `catid` = '863'" ;
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare($query1)
);
$id1 =  $wpdb->insert_id;



$query2 =  "INSERT INTO wpr9_postmeta ( `post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value` ) 
SELECT '".$id1."', 'mp3url',`image` FROM `play` WHERE `catid` = '863'" ;
$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare($query2)
);
$id2 =  $wpdb->insert_id;


$query3 =  "INSERT INTO wpr9_term_relationships ( `object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id` ) 
SELECT '".$id1."', '7' FROM `play` WHERE `catid` = '863'" ;

$wpdb->query(
    $wpdb->prepare($query3)
);
$id3 =  $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Comment: (1) Can't you copy the original `id` as well when doing the first `insert`? (2) Is there a combination of columns (other than `id`) that can be used to uniqely identify a row in the first table?

Comment: i need the id return from $query2 to insert to another table

Comment: If these aren't custom tables, why not use the standard WP functions for updating post meta etc?

Comment: there are custom table as you see `play`

Comment: You are selecting data from a custom table, but it looks like you are trying to add to the default WP tables. The WP db can be complicated to use and it is much easier to use the WP functions for doing anything with it.